# Unable to access service deployed in aws eks

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I have deployed user management service in EKS but unable to access.

```
Input : curl -v http://54.253.213.152:30077/usermgmt/health-status

Output : curl: (7) Failed to connect to 54.253.213.152 port 30077: Connection refused
```

Pods Running

---

```
mysql-cc94644fc-5g6wq                  1/1     Running   0          19h   192.168.22.212 

usermgt-microsevice-694d677968-bnlsv   1/1     Running   6          19h   192.168.56.62
```

Service

---

NAME                       TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE

```
kubernetes                 ClusterIP   10.100.0.1      <none>        443/TCP          24h

mysql                      ClusterIP   None            <none>        3306/TCP         20h

usermgmt-restapp-service   NodePort    10.100.202.28   <none>        8095:30077/TCP   20h
```

Nodes with external IPs

---

NAME                                                STATUS  EXTERNAL-IP

```
ip-192-168-0-106.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal    Ready  54.253.26.10    

ip-192-168-29-240.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal   Ready  54.79.163.174
ip-192-168-62-151.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal   Ready  54.253.213.152
```

### Security groups Added

```
HTTP TCP 80 175.45.149.101/32

All TCP TCP 0 - 65535 175.45.149.101/32

SSH TCP 22 175.45.149.101/32
```

I have tried with IP range 0.0.0.0 as we well but unable to reach to the the service.

Comment: @sudhirkumar- If you have enabled VPC Flow Logs, then you can trace vpc flow logs to check, which aws resource is rejecting the network traffic. For VPC flow logs information please refer [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/vpc-flow-logs-log-and-view-network-traffic-flows/) document from AWS.

Comment: Could you try to access it first from your eks node ? What's the result ?

Comment: @mario, there was an issue with the selector so, Node IP was not reachable. Now, it's is reachable. Also it is accessible through curl http://10.100.145.63:8095/usermgmt/health-status. However, when i do curl through external port it fails
```
curl -v http://3.24.139.47:32119/usermgmt/health-status
* Connected to 3.24.139.47 (3.24.139.47) port 32119 (#0)
> GET /usermgmt/health-status HTTP/1.1
* Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
* stopped the pause stream!
* Closing connection 0
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

```

Comment: Did you check your `Pod` logs ? Maybe there are more details there which can tell you why connectotion was reset.